# Order of contact for a general tangent line of a cubic hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For the polynomial $y=x^{3}$ it is easy to see, that for every point except $x=0$ the order of contact for a tangent line is 2.

Harris uses in his book "Algebraic geometry" the fact, that a general tangent line of a smooth cubic threefold $X$ has contact of order 2 at a general point $p\in L$, where $L$ is a line contained in $X$, to prove the unirationality of cubic threefolds. So in this case the intuition one gets from the easy case above applies to this case.

My question is, whether this is true in all dimensions, i.e. if $X$ is a smooth cubic hypersurface in projective space, is it true that for a general $p\in X$ and a general tangent line $p\in L$ the order of contact is 2?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true for all smooth cubic hypersurfaces.

A general $\mathbb P^2$ section of $X$ is a smooth plane cubic curve, and there are exactly $9$ points where tangent lines have contact order $3$ (also known as flex points).

However, if a general tangent line of $X$ has contact order $3$, then so is a general tangent line of $X$ contained in a general plane $\mathbb P^2\subset \mathbb P^N$. This says a smooth cubic curve has a dense subset of flex points. This is absurd.